# Uploading svn repository changes directly to a Production Server?

Tags: svn, command

Is it possible that i could upload my changes from the svn repository directly to my production server(2nd copy containing all the data as origional copy  but for testing purposes)?

I mean is there a way i could do it without EXPORT-> Then manually copy paste to production server...

If yes, how can i do that?

any pitfalls?

Thanks

Comment: Are you meaning the web server where the source code is or the databases where the data is? And are you running on Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option (if you don't want to have the .svn subdirectories in your production site) is to do checkout to a different area on the disk, then update that periodically, and then `rsync` that across to the production site using a command such as

```
rsync -a --exclude='*/.svn/*' checkout_dir site_dir
```

The `svn update` and `rsync` commands will run very quickly compared to doing a full `svn export` every time.

Comment: Perhaps an even better option. Nice.

Comment: That's actually a really great idea and I think I'll integrate that into my build process.

Comment: Also if you're on Windows you can use [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) with the `/mir` option to do a similar thing to rsync

Comment: Actually you can request `rsync` to ignore **ALL** VCS files and dotfiles with the `-C` flag

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're currently `svn export`ing your files to your server... if that's the case, you could instead just `svn checkout` on your production machine and `svn up` when you've made changes to the repository, and that'll only sync the files you've changed. If you go this route, it's of course important to restrict access via your web server's configuration (assuming this is a web app) to any `.svn` directories.

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175056/svn-checkout-or-export-for-production-environment) for a better explanation.